# File Object Size Larger than Memory Increase Recorded After Reading it

Tags: python, memory

I wasn't expecting the output shown below after running this code and wanted to see if anyone can explain it.

Line 9 reads a file into memory, and running memory_profiler shows memory usage increases by 374 MB at this line.

But at line 11 the size of the file object is printed using sys.getsizeof(). Can anyone explain why the size of the object appears to be larger than the memory usage increment recorded after reading it?

```
import os
import math
import sys
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

@profile
def my_func():
    with open('f.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
    size = str(round(sys.getsizeof(content)/1000000))
    print('The size of the file object is: ' + size + ' MB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

**Output**

```
The size of the file object is: 392 MB
Filename: memorydemo.py
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6   17.898 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     7                             def my_func():
     8   17.898 MiB    0.000 MiB    with open('f.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as content_file:
     9  392.082 MiB  374.184 MiB        content = content_file.read()
    10  392.090 MiB    0.008 MiB    size = str(round(sys.getsizeof(content)/1000000))
    11  392.090 MiB    0.000 MiB    print('The size of the file object is: ' + size + ' MB')
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks mkrieger1 and Some programmer dude for explaining:

1048576 * 374.184 = 392360361 bytes

That explains the output of sys.getsizeof()

Comment: You don't tell us what output you get. Please edit your question to include the actual and expected output.

Comment: Oh by the way, remember that a kilobyte is not really 1000, due to how the binary system work, it's 1024. That in turn means that an MB is not exactly 1000000 either, it is 1048576 (1024*1024).

Comment: Actually, 1 MB = 1000000 Bytes, but 1 MiB = 1048576 Bytes (as seen in the output). Only in common speech "MiB" is pronounced "megabyte".